# MKMapView leaks when removing Annotations or just me?

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, mkmapview, mkannotation

I'm getting leaks of my annotations. The code (stripped down to its bear minimum) in question is:

```
- (void)updateLocations:(NSArray *)result {
    [mapView removeAnnotations:locations];
    [locations removeAllObjects];
    [allLocations removeAllObjects];
    for (NSDictionary *location in result) {
        LocationAnnotation *annote = [[LocationAnnotation alloc] initWithInfo:location];
        [allLocations addObject:annote];
        [annote release];
    }
    [self updateAnnotations];
}

- (void)filterLocations {
    for (LocationAnnotation *annote in allLocations) {
        if (annote.typeFlag & filterFlags) {
            [locations addObject:annote];
        }
    }
}

- (void)updateAnnotations {
    [self filterLocations];
    [mapView addAnnotations:locations];
}

- (void)updateFilter {
    [mapView removeAnnotations:locations];
    [locations removeAllObjects];
    [self updateAnnotations];
}
```

`allLocations` is an array that contains all the annotations (they are not necessarily on the map), and `locations` is an array that holds the locations that are actually displayed in the map. When `updateLocations:` is called, some (or all, it changes from test to test) of the annotations added to the map are leaking. The allocation history of the annotations is:

```
#   Category            Event Type  Timestamp   RefCt   Address     Size    Responsible Library Responsible Caller
0   LocationAnnotation  Malloc      16421111296 1       0x4953870   64      MyApp               -[MapViewController updateLocations:]
1   LocationAnnotation  Retain      16421383424 2       0x4953870   0       MyApp               -[MapViewController updateLocations:]
2   LocationAnnotation  Release     16421391104 1       0x4953870   0       MyApp               -[MapViewController updateLocations:]
3   LocationAnnotation  Retain      16444210176 2       0x4953870   0       MyApp               -[MapViewController filterLocations]
4   LocationAnnotation  Retain      16557738240 3       0x4953870   0       MapKit              -[MKQuadTrie insert:]
5   LocationAnnotation  Retain      16557750272 4       0x4953870   0       MapKit              -[MKAnnotationContainerView addAnnotation:]
6   LocationAnnotation  Retain      16564529408 5       0x4953870   0       MapKit              -[MKQuadTrie insert:]
7   LocationAnnotation  Release     17296397312 4       0x4953870   0       MapKit              -[MKAnnotationContainerView showAddedAnnotationsAnimated:]
8   LocationAnnotation  Retain      21832317184 5       0x4953870   0       MapKit              -[MKAnnotationContainerView removeAnnotation:]
9   LocationAnnotation  Autorelease 21832324096         0x4953870   0       MapKit              -[MKAnnotationContainerView removeAnnotation:]
10  LocationAnnotation  Release     21832350208 4       0x4953870   0       MapKit              -[MKQuadTrie remove:]
11  LocationAnnotation  Release     21920062208 3       0x4953870   0       MyApp               -[MapViewController updateLocations:]
12  LocationAnnotation  Release     21923836416 2       0x4953870   0       MyApp               -[MapViewController updateLocations:]
13  LocationAnnotation  Release     22050286336 1       0x4953870   0       Foundation          -[NSAutoreleasePool drain]
```

And looking at this it seems the culprit is that `[MKQuadTrie insert:]` is called twice while only one `[MKQuadTrie remove:]` is called. Am I missing something and its my fault or is it a bug in MKMapKit?

Edit: I have seen an allocation histroy with 14 [MKQuadTrie insert:] calls and only 1 [MKQuadTrie remove:]

Answer (score 5):

Ok i solved this problem for me

I was trying to remove all the annotations and add new ones (but my code was making sure it didn't remove the user location). It was something to do with that code

I replaced it with this

```
[self.map removeAnnotations: [self.map.annotations filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"!(self isKindOfClass: %@)", [MKUserLocation class]]]];
```

And now i don't get the same issue.

Comment: Well I have no time to look into this at the moment, but thinking about it the only thing I can think of that would make that fix the problem (unless you actually didn't have all your annotations in your own array that you pass to `removeAnnotiations:`), is that `map.annotations` contains some annotations multiple times and `removeAnnotations:` only removes the first occurrences of the annotations you pass in. Thus `[map removeAnnotations:map.annotations]` works because you are passing an array that also has the multiple occurrences. Thanks for the reply, i'll look into it asap!